# Semantic UI Popup doesn't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm making my first steps with Semantic UI and even got the first problems I can't fix.

I just want to create a simple popup trigger like here http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#specifying-a-trigger-event .
I've tried to copy and paste the `.html` and `.js` code and also inlcuded the `semantic.min.js` and `semantic.min.css` in the page header, but it doesn't open the popup for whatever reason.

Here's the html code I use:

```
<div class="ui singleImg container">
    <div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
    <div class="ui two column stackable grid">
      <div class="eleven wide column">
          <h1 class="ui dividing header">Test</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="five wide column">
        <div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Download</div>
        Sidebar
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And before `</body>` I've also added the following `.js` code:

```
<script>
    $('.teal.button')
      .popup({
        on: 'click'
      })
    ;
</script>
```

**//Update:**
Created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/w46ynjwu/

Comment: Check your console for errors, the errors you receive are quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem in your code you did not add jquery.

here is a (almost)same [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fjLwyaf/) working fine

```
<script>//no need of this tag in jsfiddle
</script>
```

Comment: Yes you're right, but in the online version I had jQuery added, but your answer helped me a lot cause it seems like another script has overwritten the $ of my included jquery :)

Thx :)